# Reading commands from stderr

Tags: command-line

In the Vim man page, I came across the following option:

```
-  The file to edit is read from stdin.  Commands are read from stderr, which should be a tty.
```

I think I'm misunderstanding this, as I can't control Vim via stderr, like so:

```sh
( echo 'Hi, from the buffer!' && echo ':q!' >&2 ) | vim -
```

What is meant by "*Commands are read from stderr*"?

Comment: Could you tell us which OS are you using (Windows, Linux, macOS)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt the term "man page" made me assume non-Windows. What OP quotes can be found in `man vim` in e.g. Debian. BTW, I don't understand what it's supposed to mean either... I'd just happily ignore it :-)

Comment: I found something in the doc about the `-` command line argument but I didn't manage to made à working use case yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out. Here's how I sent commands to Vim through `stderr` via a named pipe in Bash:

```bash
# Create a named pipe
controller='/tmp/vim-control'
if [ ! -e "$controller" ]; then
    mkfifo "$controller" 2>/dev/null || printf 'Error: mkfifo failed "%s"\n' "$controller"
else
    printf 'Error: "%s" already exists\n' "$controller"
fi

# Set up trap to remove the named pipe on shell exit
trap 'rm -rf "$controller"' EXIT

# Define a Bash command to send commands to Vim
send-cmd() {
    stdbuf -oL printf '\e:%s\n' "$@" > "$controller"
}

# Open another terminal, and start Vim
printf "Vahu\nVuya\nVipa\nVaho\nVoke\n" | /usr/bin/vim - 2<>/tmp/vim-control

# Flip back to the first terminal and run a test command
send-cmd ":echowindow 'Affirmative, Dave. I read you.'"
```

I have no use case for this, but I had never heard of **reading + writing** to `stderr` and was curious if this was a mistake in the man page — turns out it wasn't.

Comment: Why doesn't the original command in the question work? Is the problem that the echo is writing to stderr *before* Vim is running so it never sees it?

Comment: The &&|| won’t do what you think if the file doesn’t exist but mkfifo fails. You probably actually want an if/else there.

Answer (score 2):

> What is meant by "Commands are read from stderr"?

It means that commands are read from file descriptor 2.

Example using [here strings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html):

```sh
vim - <<< "Hello, World!" 2<<< ":w! file.txt | :q"
cat file.txt
```